# Brauer group of a subfield

Tags: tensor-products, noncommutative-algebra, division-algebras, brauer-group

Let $A$ be a central simple algebra with a finite dimension over the field $F$.

Let $A \supset K \supset F$ be a subfield.

Show that $C_A(K)$ and $A \otimes_F K$ are both central simple algebras over the center K. and also $[C_A(K)] = [A \otimes_F K]$ in Brauer group $B(K)$

---

Well , I have a proof for the first part but for the last part, I have completely no idea..

I think it might be connected to the fact that $A \cong K \otimes_F C_A(K)$

Thanks !

Comment: A few quick comments: it is not true that a tensor product of simple algebras is simple, and it is also not true that a subalgebra of a simple algebra is simple.

Comment: Where did you get that last "fact" from? Consider the case $F=\Bbb{Q}$, $K=\Bbb{Q}(i)$, $A=$ the division algebra of Hamiltonian quaternions with rational coefficients. $K$ is a maximal subfield, so it is equal to its own centralizer. Therefore $K\otimes_FC_A(K)$ is commutative (more precisely, a direct sum of two copies of $K$)?